# NameError: uninitialized constant Twilio::JWT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-2.4

Getting an error while trying to generate access token for video
Using twilio-ruby (4.11.1), ruby 2.4.1, rails 5.1.0.

Code:

```
    # Create an Access Token
    token = Twilio::JWT::AccessToken.new(account_sid, api_key, api_secret, identity);
```

following the twilio official Doc.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/user-identity-access-tokens#ruby

Error which am facing:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Twilio::JWT
```

Comment: Have you got a `require: false` or anything in your Gemfile?

Comment: Sure you have `require 'twilio-ruby'` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That example code appears to be written for the upcoming version 5 of the [Twilio Ruby gem](http://twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby). The [version 5 gem is at rc23](https://rubygems.org/gems/twilio-ruby/versions/5.0.0.rc23) so I recommend using that to create your access token as it has the methods required to make a Video Grant for the rooms API.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: i have created an issue on github, it should work with  rc24, as rc23 still has issues with Authentication::VideoGrant.

I have accepted your answer, please update the rc23 to rc24

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/issues/283

Comment: Thanks for raising that, looks like it's getting sorted quickly!